# Hibernate search mass index with Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search

I've got a project that I've just converted to Spring Data JPA. The project uses Hibernate Search, and I need a way to index the existing (~15 million) records in the database.

Since I'm dealing with such a large number of records, I can't use Hibernate Search's MassIndexer, as this causes out of memory issues.

From what I've read (here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html/manual-index-changes.html#search-batchindex), the suggested way to do this is something like this:

```
fullTextSession.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
fullTextSession.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
transaction = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
//Scrollable results will avoid loading too many objects in memory
ScrollableResults results = fullTextSession.createCriteria( Email.class )
    .setFetchSize(BATCH_SIZE)
    .scroll( ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY );
int index = 0;
while( results.next() ) {
    index++;
    fullTextSession.index( results.get(0) ); //index each element
    if (index % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
        fullTextSession.flushToIndexes(); //apply changes to indexes
        fullTextSession.clear(); //free memory since the queue is processed
    }
}
transaction.commit();
```

However, I'd like to inject the entity manager I've configured in Spring.

I've read that I can get the Hibernate session by using the `getDelegate()` method on the entity manager, but this results in an error stating that the Hibernate session is closed as soon as I try to set any properties on the session:

```
public void reindexListings() throws InterruptedException {

   Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();

   FullTextSession fts = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

   try {
      fts.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // Throws stack trace here stating that the Hibernate session is closed.
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

   fts.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
   Transaction transaction = fts.beginTransaction();

   // Scrollable results will avoid loading too many objects in memory
   ScrollableResults results = fts.createCriteria(EListing.class)
         .setFetchSize(25).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
   int index = 0;
   while (results.next()) {
      index++;
      fts.index(results.get(0)); // index each element
      if ((index % 25) == 0) {
         fts.flushToIndexes(); // apply changes to indexes
         fts.clear(); // free memory since the queue is processed
      }
   }

   transaction.commit();

}
```

I've also read that I can use `HibernateUtil` to obtain a session (http://www.17od.com/2006/11/06/using-managed-sessions-in-hibernate-to-ease-unit-testing/), but again, this doesn't make use of my entity manager.

Not sure if I'm on the right track so far, or if I need to do this an entirely different way, but nothing I've found so far seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MassIndexer is designed for large amounts of data and should not cause out of memory issues.

If you're using MySQL, did you notice the warning on the reference:

> The MassIndexer uses a forward only scrollable result to iterate on
>   the primary keys to be loaded, but MySQL's JDBC driver will load all
>   values in memory; to avoid this "optimisation" set idFetchSize to
>   Integer.MIN_VALUE.

If that's not the problem, try setting the MassIndexer options to less aggressive values:

```
fullTextSession.createIndexer()
   .threadsForSubsequentFetching( X )
   .threadsToLoadObjects( Y )
   .batchSizeToLoadObjects( Z )
   .progressMonitor( progressMonitor )
   .startAndWait();
```

Or just tune your heap size to a larger value: reindexing all that stuff will take time, so if you can give it more memory it will be significantly more efficient.

Use *MassIndexer.limitIndexedObjectsTo(long)* to experiment with different values, but keep in mind it needs at least 15 minutes to settle down on average performance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Turns out that my issue was not the MassIndexer after all. The query generated by my entity relations resulted in no candidates for indexing. My assumption was that the MassIndexer was holding documents in memory until the end of the process, which never finished because I had so many entities to cycle through. Setting the limit on the indexed objects allowed me to complete the indexing process and showed me that this was not the case. From there, I was able to investigate further and discovered the real issue. Thanks again.